# lazy suspense not working in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

Considering this component

```
import React, {lazy, Suspense} from "react"
import {View, StyleSheet, Text, ScrollView} from "react-native"

const Sections = lazy(() => import('./story/Sections'))

export default StoryScreen = (props) => (

  <Suspense fallback={<Text>Loading...</Text>}>
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <ScrollView style={styles.sectionContainer}>
        <Sections sections={props.item.sections}/>
      </ScrollView>
    </View>
  </Suspense>
)
```

with **Sections.js** as

```
import React from "react"
import Section from "./Section"

export default Sections = (props) => (
  props.sections.map((section) => (
    <Section key={section.id_section} {...section}/>
  ))
)
```

The error I'm receiving when navigating to the component is:[image]

I don't know where I'm doing wrong. Any clue?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in your Sections component. You are returning an array of JSX elements, which itself is not a valid JSX element that a component can return. For this to work, you must wrap the array of Sections you create with another JSX tag, the easiest being a Fragment. This will be valid JSX, and will render properly.

```js
import React from "react"
import Section from "./Section"

export default Sections = (props) => (
  <>
    {props.sections.map((section) => (
      <Section key={section.id_section} {...section}/>
    ))}
  </>
)
```